# Linux routing does not use specific route

Tags: linux, routing

On openSUSE (Leap 15.3)
i have the routing table:

```
0.0.0.0         AAA.BBB.145.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
AAA.BBB.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.178.0   192.168.178.1   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1
```

AAA.BBB.145.1 is the default Gateway (outside)
192.168.178.0 ist the internal network via eth1

I can access the outer network through default gateway.
I can directly access the second (internal) network, eg 192.168.178.11

But i can´t access it with service, for example with firefox or wget because then the system is trying to get to the host 192.168.178.11 via the external Gateway AAA.BBB.145.1  which of course doesnt know anything about my internal network.

I though i could advise Linux to route all traffic to internal network 192.168.178.0 via 192.168.178.1 but Linux seems not to recognize my wish so i suppose that i have configured the dedicated route over eth1 wrong?

Comment: What's the IP address of this system? 0.0.0.0 in routing usually translates to "unknown address", so the first route "send all traffic to unknown addresses to AAA.BBB.145.1". But that second route... "send all traffic to AAA.BBB.0.0 to unknown address"???

Comment: You should provide information using the newer (since more than 20 years) iproute2 tools rather than the Linux-deprecated `route` command: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route` to clarify a few things. (note that `ip route` is not `route`).

Answer (score 0):

I turned out that the routing tables are fine.

The fact that i could ping to devices internal in the network eth1 AND that firefox was not able to do that made me investigate Firefox proxie Configuration and it turned out that Firefox routed the internal addresses to the Firefox proxie which resides of course on the external net (and didnt find the internal adress). Althought address 192.168.178.0 was in the list which should exclude the proxie, Firefox didnt do that and i had to put the fully qualified address 192.168.178.X into the Proxie-Excluding list. After that, Firefox could reach the host on the internal network. (Didnt try it with "wget" yet)

(For clarification in this small environment:

> `0.0.0.0    AAA.BBB.145.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0`

Default route (all packets which are not handled by other route entries are deleivered to the next Router (e.g. to next Gateway outside) AAA.BBB.145.1)

> `AAA.BBB.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0`

Adresses with AAA.BBB.NNN.MMM/16 are seen as local addresses attached to the local network and are send directly to the machines on the local attached network (underlying switches/router/networks are not important for the host because the underlying network structure/architecture will handle this)

> `192.168.178.0     192.168.178.1   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1`

Addresses with 192.168.178.X are delivered to the network eth1)